# ref vs reactive in Vue 3?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Looking at some examples of some people's preview tutorials for Vue 3. [Currently beta right now]

I've found two examples:

### Reactive

```js
<template>
  <button @click="increment">
    Count is: {{ state.count }}, double is: {{ state.double }}
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive, computed } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      count: 0,
      double: computed(() => state.count * 2)
    })

    function increment() {
      state.count++
    }

    return {
      state,
      increment
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

### Ref

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h2 ref="titleRef">{{ formattedMoney }}</h2>
    <input v-model="delta" type="number">
    <button @click="add">Add</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, computed, onMounted } from "vue";

export default {
  setup(props) {
    // State
    const money = ref(1);
    const delta = ref(1);

    // Refs
    const titleRef = ref(null);

    // Computed props
    const formattedMoney = computed(() => money.value.toFixed(2));

    // Hooks
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log("titleRef", titleRef.value);
    });

    // Methods
    const add = () => (money.value += Number(delta.value));

    return {
      delta,
      money,
      titleRef,
      formattedMoney,
      add
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 478, accepted):

#### Key Points

- `reactive()` only takes objects, **NOT** JS primitives *(String, Boolean, Number, BigInt, Symbol, null, undefined)*
- `ref()` is calling `reactive()` behind the scenes
- Since `reactive()` works for objects and `ref()` calls `reactive()`, objects work for both
- BUT, `ref()` has a `.value` property for reassigning, `reactive()` does not have this and therefore CANNOT be reassigned

#### Use

`ref()` when..

- it's a primitive *(for example `'string'`, `true`, `23`, etc)*
- it's an object you need to later reassign (like an array - [more info here](https://github.com/vuejs/docs-next/issues/801#issuecomment-757587022))

`reactive()` when..

- it's an object you don't need to reassign, and you want to avoid the overhead of `ref()`

#### In Summary

`ref()` seems like the way to go since it supports all object types and allows reassigning with `.value`. `ref()` is a good place to start, but as you get used to the API, know that `reactive()` has less overhead, and you may find it better meets your needs.

#### `ref()` Use-Case

You'll always use `ref()` for primitives, but `ref()` is good for objects that need to be reassigned, like an array.

```js
setup() {
    const blogPosts = ref([]);
    return { blogPosts };
}
getBlogPosts() {
    this.blogPosts.value = await fetchBlogPosts();
}
```

The above with `reactive()` would require reassigning a property instead of the whole object.

```js
setup() {
    const blog = reactive({ posts: [] });
    return { blog };
}
getBlogPosts() {
    this.blog.posts = await fetchBlogPosts();
}
```

#### `reactive()` Use-Case

A good use-case for `reactive()` is a group of primitives that belong together:

```js
const person = reactive({
  name: 'Albert',
  age: 30,
  isNinja: true,
});
```

the code above feels more logical than

```js
const name = ref('Albert');
const age = ref(30);
const isNinja = ref(true);
```

#### Useful Links

If you're still lost, this simple guide helped me: https://www.danvega.dev/blog/2020/02/12/vue3-ref-vs-reactive/

An argument for only ever using `ref()`: https://dev.to/ycmjason/thought-on-vue-3-composition-api-reactive-considered-harmful-j8c

The decision-making behind why `reactive()` and `ref()` exist as they do and other great information, the Vue Composition API RFC: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/composition-api-faq.html#why-composition-api

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#usage-inside-v-for  what's the difference between const list = reactive([1, 2, 3]) and const divs = ref([]) ?

Comment: @Yiping good point. An array is an object, and both accept objects, so I wasn't sure. But, turns out there are advantages to reassigning arrays with `ref`'s `.value` that `reactive` doesn't have. https://github.com/vuejs/docs-next/issues/801#issuecomment-757587022

Comment: I've updated the answer with more information and examples.

Comment: reactive can be reassigned by Object.assign()

Comment: @Bryant Object.assign merges objects. It does not reassign. Consider you have two reactives: one to store the original state and another to store modified state. If you attempt to use Object.assign to revert modified back to the original state you'll get a merged object instead.
`const original = reactive({name: "Original"})`
`const modified = reactive({name: "Modified", age: 5})`
`Object.assign(modified, original);` => {name: 'Original', age: 5}

Comment: can we use array in ref ?

Comment: This is perhaps the best answer and best documented one. Clear, neat and straight to the point, plus providing examples.

This should be in the official Vue docs. Not kidding

Comment: If you want a more detailed response, I spent a long time researching and writing my own thoughts on this question: https://michaelnthiessen.com/ref-vs-reactive/

Comment: @MichaelThiessen nice article, "Use reactive where you want to 'reactify' some other JS object like a Map or Set." is a good point.

Comment: I am surprised no one mentioned that `ref` binds to the DOM elements by name and `reactive` does not. Use `ref` if and only if you are meaning to reference a DOM primitive directly; otherwise use `reactive` or embrace the unexpected behavior (when some DOM element reference matches your variable name). https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html

Answer (score 29):

There are some similarities between `ref` and `reactive`, in that they  both provide a method to store data and allow that data to be reactive.

However:

**High level differences:**

> You can’t use reactive() on primitives (strings, numbers, booleans) - that’s what you need refs for, because you will have situations where you need to have a “reactive boolean”, for example…
>
> of course your can create an object that wraps the primitive value and make that reactive():

```
const wrappedBoolean = reactive({
  value: true
})
```

> and just like that, you reinvented a ref.

[Source: Vue forum discussion](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-3-ref-vs-reactive/86680/2)

**Reactive**

`reactive` takes the object and returns a reactive `proxy` to the original object.

**Example**

```
import {ref, reactive} from "vue";

export default {
  name: "component",
  setup() {
    const title = ref("my cool title")
    const page = reactive({
      contents: "meh?",
      number: 1,
      ads: [{ source: "google" }],
      filteredAds: computed(() => {
        return ads.filter(ad => ad.source === "google")
      })
    })
    
    return {
       page, 
       title
    }
  }
}
```

**Explanation**

In the above, Whenever we want to change or access the properties of `page`,
say `page.ads`, `page.filteredAds` will update via Proxies.

Comment: Is there any opinion on which is best for arrays? That is, `ref([])` vs. `reactive([])`?

Answer (score 22):

#### I will simply explain why there are 2 ways of creating a reactive state:

*Other answers already show the differences between the two*

---

> #### `reactive`: Create a reactive state. Returns a reactive proxy of the object:

```js
import { reactive } from 'vue'

const reactiveObj = reactive({ count: 0 })
reactiveObj.count++
```

*With Options API we used to keep reactive state in `data()`. With Composition API we can achieve the same with `reactive` API. So far, so good, but...*

> #### Why do we need `ref` ???

Simply because `reactive` has limitations such as:

- Reactivity loss:

```js
const state = reactive({ count: 0 })

// the function receives a plain number and
// won't be able to track changes to state.count
callSomeFunction(state.count)
```

```js
const state = reactive({ count: 0 })
let { count } = state
// does not affect original state
count++
```

```js
let state = reactive({ count: 0 })

// this won't work!
state = reactive({ count: 1 })
```

- It cannot hold primitive types such as string, number or boolean.

> #### So `ref`, was provided by Vue to address the limitations of `reactive`.

`ref()` takes the argument and returns it wrapped within a ref object with a .value property:

```js
const count = ref(0)

console.log(count) // { value: 0 }
console.log(count.value) // 0

count.value++
console.log(count.value) // 1
```

Refs can:

- hold any value type
- reactively replace the entire object:

```js
const objectRef = ref({ count: 0 })

// this works reactively
objectRef.value = { count: 1 }
```

- be passed into functions or destructured from plain objects without losing reactivity

```js
const obj = {
  foo: ref(1),
  bar: ref(2)
}

// the function receives a ref
// it needs to access the value via .value but it
// will retain the reactivity connection
callSomeFunction(obj.foo)

// still reactive
const { foo, bar } = obj
```

---

> #### Should I always use `ref`?

*Personal opinion follows*

Most devs who have tried both, suggest using `ref` from articles that I have read.

But personally, I think that `ref` has the same limitation as `reactive` if not used correctly and you can easily fall into "Reactivity loss" issues.
`ref` has also some behaviors like:

- unwrapping in templates but that happens only to top-level properties
- unwrapping inside `reactive`
- no unwrapping is performed when the ref is accessed from an array or a native collection type like Map
- Synchronization of refs

Also having to deal with `.value` every time is a bit confusing, Vue knows that and there is an [RFC - Reactivity Transform](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/369) as of this time of writing that aims to provide a solution.

I hope you now have a better understanding of `reactive` and `ref` but I think is worth mentioning that there more APIs for reactive state that you should be aware of: readonly, shallowRef, shallowReactive, shallowReadonly, unref, and many more.

Answer (score 3):

ref / reactive both are been used to create reactive object where the changes been tracked.

### Ref :

It takes an primitives argument and return a reactive mutable object. The object has single property ‘value’ and it will point to the argument taken by it.

### Reactive :

It takes a JavaScript object as a argument and returns Proxy based reactive copy of the object.

### Ref vs Reactive :

Typically, ref and reactive both have been used to create reactive objects where ref is used to make the primitive values to be reactive (Boolean, Number, String). But reactive won’t work with primitives rather than it works for objects.

For further details : Refer [Ref vs Reactive](https://programeasily.com/2020/12/17/ref-vs-reactive-in-vue-3/)

Answer (score 2):

Although others have already answered this question, I would like to summarize my understanding after conducting research. I believe this summary will be helpful for newbies who are just starting with Vue 3. Many thanks to all the posts and blogs in this thread.

## 1. `Reactive` Limitations

### Limited value types

- It only works for object types (objects, arrays, and collection types such as Map and Set). [Doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#limitations-of-reactive)

```
const reactiveNumber = reactive(0) // won't work
```

### Easier to reactivity loss

- `ref` has the `.value` property to remind us that it holds reactive data, while `reactive` objects lack this property. This can lead to loss of reactivity if not used carefully.

```
let reactiveArray = reactive([1, 2, 3]);
let refArray = ref([1, 2, 3]);

setTimeout(() => {
  // We've replaced it with an entirely new, non-reactive object
  reactiveArray = [4, 5, 6];

  refArray = [4, 5, 6]; // Warning when using with ref
}, 1000)

watchEffect(() => console.log(reactiveArray)); // Won't trigger for [4, 5, 6]
```

## 2. `Ref` Limitations

### Inconsistent when using .value

- Inconsitent when unwrap `ref` value. Some places we can use a `ref` directly, some places we have to use `ref.value`. [Doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping-as-reactive-object-property)

```
<template>
  <!-- Dont need .value because of ref template unwrapping -->
  {{ refString }} 
  <button @click="mutateRef">Mutate</button>

  <!-- Need .value if ref isnt a top-level property -->
  <p>{{ user.age.value + 1 }}</p>
  
  <!-- Dont need .value if it is the final evaluated value of a text interpolation -->
  <p>{{ user.age}} </p>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { reactive, ref } from 'vue';
const refString = ref("abc");

// Need use .value to access/mutate ref value here
const mutateRef = (): void => {
  refString.value = "def";
}

const user = {
  age: ref(20)
}

const count = ref(0)

// Dont need .value if ref is property of reactive object
const state1 = reactive({count})
console.log(state1.count) // 0

// But need .value if ref is property of reactive array
const state2 = reactive([count])
console.log(state2[0].value) // 0

// But need .value if ref is property of reactive collection
const state3 = reactive(new Map([['count', count]]))
console.log(state3.get('count')!.value) // 0

</script>
```

## 3. Why `ref` is more prefer than `reactive`

- https://dev.to/ycmjason/thought-on-vue-3-composition-api-reactive-considered-harmful-j8c
- https://michaelnthiessen.com/ref-vs-reactive

### Flexiblility

- `reactive` only takes object. `ref` can hold any value type

```
const reactiveNumber = reactive(0) // won't work
```

### Explicitness

- `.value` may seem wordy as first, but it helps reminding us that we are dealing with reactivity.
- It's very easy to incorrectly use `reactive` and lose reactivity without realizing what's happening. Because it doesn't have `.value` to remind us

```
// This is likely a reative value using ref
someRef.value = 'New value'

// Is this going to update reactively or just a simple object
// It's impossible to know just from looking at this line
someObject.property = 'New value'
```

### Convenience

- If you return an object where each property is a `ref` from a composition function, you can destruct it safely. Otherwise we have to use `toRefs`

```
const useData = () => {
  const firstName = ref('John');
  const lastName = ref('Doe');
  const age = ref(30);

  return { firstName, lastName, age };
};

// In component
...
const { firstName, lastName, age } = useData();
```

- Using `template refs`. We can use `template reactive`, but it requires a bit of extra syntax using function `ref`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 :ref="(el) => {heading.element = el}">
      Heading
    </h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  const heading = reactive(null)
</script>
```

### Unavoidable

- `ref` cannot be avoided since `computed` returns a ref, and we also have `template ref`.
- Use `toRefs()` or `toRef()` to safely destruct objects and maintain reactivity from `props` or composable function

Answer (score 1):

Below you can see our example using Reactive References on the upper part, and below other alternative reactive syntax.

```
//reactivity with ref syntax

import { ref, computed } from vue

export default {
  setup() {
    const capacity = ref(4)
    const members = ref(["Tim", "John", "Andr"])
    const simpleComputed = computed(() => {
      return capacity.value - members.value.length
    })

    return { capacity, members, simpleComputed }
  }
}


//reactivity with reactive syntax

import { reactive, computed } from vue

export default {
  setup() {
    const event = reactive({
      capacity: 4,
      members: ["Tim", "John", "Andr"]
      simpleComputed: computed(() => {
        return event.capacity - event.capacity.length
      }
    })
    return { event }
  }
}
```

As it shows in the code above on the bottom part, I created a new event constant which takes a plain JavaScript object and returns a reactive object. This may look familiar to using the data option in our regular component syntax, where I also send in an object. However, as you can see above, I can also send in our computed properties into this object. You should also notice that when I use this syntax we no longer need to write .value when accessing properties. This is because I am simply accessing the object properties on the event object. You should also notice that we’re returning the entire event

**Both syntaxes are valid for usage, and neither is deemed as best practice**

Answer (score 0):

`ref` object takes an inner value and returns a reactive and mutable object. usually used for primitive type single variables such as String, Boolean, Number, etc.

`reactive` is a wrapper object that takes an object and returns a reactive proxy of the original object. usually used for dictionary-structured types such as JS Object.

You can learn more about ref vs reactive in this article:
https://dev.to/hirajatamil/must-know-ref-vs-reactive-differences-in-vue-3-composition-api-3bp4

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to pick one:

- use `ref` when you need to track the value replacement (if you re-assign value), be that complex or simple value. You will have to access it's contents via `.value`.
- if you don't need to track value replacement, use `reactive` for objects and arrays.

Keep in mind, that both `reactive` and `ref` (which uses `reactive` under the hood) makes the passed object or array deep reactive, which adds some overhead. If you want to avoid that, I would suggest using `shallowRef` and `shallowReactive` instead.

See https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html for more details :)