# Vue 3 composition API - ref() vs reactive() for arrays

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

The guidance in Vue 3 documentation and in folk literature is that `ref()` is for scalars and primitives, while `reactive()` is for Objects.

However, in JavaScript, arrays are a special case of Object. Notwithstanding issues such as monitoring nested object elements for new property additions and other wrinkles, is there a best practice on whether to handle arrays as `ref` or `reactive`, whether from a performance perspective or any other?

Comment: If you pass an Array (hence, an Object) to `ref`, [it will be converted to a `reactive`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/master/packages/reactivity/src/ref.ts#L31), so making it a `reactive` right away makes more sense. Note: the `isObject` method used for the check in the previous link [uses `typeof x === "object"`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/master/packages/shared/src/index.ts#L71), which the case for an Array

Comment: Are you sure about that? I just checked by creating a `ref([])` in a `setup()` function; `isReactive(x)` returns `false`, while `isRef(x)` returns `true`.

Comment: This question is actually comprehensively answered (including for arrays) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65262638/645016

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ref vs reactive in Vue 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452458/ref-vs-reactive-in-vue-3)

Comment: This question has stalled without a good answer. I've voted to close in favour of the one linked to by sxc731

Answer (score -1):

I would use ref for primitive values as you already mentioned. For object type (objects or Arrays), I would advice to use the reactive property. This makes your code easier to read and removes the ".value" you would have to add when using the ref property.

Answer (score -2):

I would say, only use `ref` when you cannot use `reactive`. In your template they are pretty much the same because `ref` is automatically unwrapped. But in your code you have to remember that anything you created with `ref` will be a `Ref` - you need to manually unwrap it by calling `.value`, for most of the time.

You can `ref` around arrays and objects, but you still need to call `.value` afterwards. `ref(x)` does not "upgrade" automatically to `reactive(x)` just because `x` is an object (even though internally `ref(object)` might be calling `reactive` at some point).

There are a few cases when you don't need to manually unwrap, e.g. if you assign your ref to a property of a reactive object. But this is actually what makes it confusing and error-prone.

Btw if you use typescript, reactive around primitives will report error right away and that is the time you know you need to use ref.