# Vuejs Iterate through a ref object

Tags: javascript, loops, iterator, vuejs3

I have a small problem,
I get my ref object from that method

```
const dataAnimals = ref([])
function getDataAnimals() {
  axios.get('/json/data_animal.json').then((response) => {
    dataAnimals.value = response.data
  })
}
getDataAnimals()
```

And i want to use another method using that ref object :

```
function countAnimal(type) {
  dataAnimals.forEach((item) => {
    if (animal.animal == type) {
      total_hen += dataMint.value[animal.template_id]
    }
    return total_hen
  })
}
const totalHen = countAnimal('hen')
```

But i can't iterate through :

```
dataAnimals.value.forEach((item) => {
```

Is there anyway to make that work ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you sure, the `response.data` is actually returning an array? Maybe it is an object containing an array?

Comment: Hello Thomas, here is the reponse.data content :  https://prnt.sc/1yvhnkq and here is the dataAnimals : https://prnt.sc/1yvhsau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the response is an object and not an array, you cannot iterate over it with `forEach`, you need to use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
function countAnimal(type) {
    let total = 0;
    for (const [key, item] of Object.entries(dataAnimals)) {
        if (item.animal === type)  {
            total++;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
const totalHen = countAnimal('hen');
```

And I would use a reactive object:

```
const dataAnimals = ref(null);
function getDataAnimals() {
    axios.get('/json/data_animal.json').then((response) => {
        dataAnimals.value = response.data
    });
}
getDataAnimals()
```

Of course if you want that count to be reactive as well you'd need to use a computed property.

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me !
Why would you use a reactive object instead of a ref object ?

Comment: There is no real rule for it, in this case ref would probably be even the better case (I'll edit the code). There is a good break down: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452458/ref-vs-reactive-in-vue-3

Comment: I'm using this exact format "for (const [key, item] of Object.entries(images))" but 'item' is another proxy object that looks exactly like the original images object, but with one element rather than many, so I have to use item[0].filename to get to the contents. Is this normal or have I stuffed something up?

Comment: I had to use "for (const [key, item] of Object.entries(images.value))" to get this to work.