# Vue Composition API: Init variable in mounted back to setup

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I try the new composition api.

composable function useProdcut.js:

```
export default function useProduct() {
     const product = reactive({});
    
   async function getProduct(id) {
     try{ 
       const response = await {{http Request}}
       product.value = response.data; // it is a single object
     }catch(err) {
       console.log(err);
     }
   } 
    return {product, getProduct}
}
```

In my component I use two composable functions:

```
setup(_, {root}) {
…
const { product, getProduct} = useProduct();

const {productAlias, productTitle, createdAt, …} = useProductDetails(prodcut);

onBeforeMount(async () => {
loading.value = true;
await getProduct(root.$route.params.id);
loading.value = false;
});

return {loading, product, productAlias, …}
}
```

In useProductDetails.js I got the message:

> product.value is undefined.

I think this is because of the value for product is retrieved in onBeforeMount. But how can I achieve to pass the product ref with value after mounted? Or is there an other way?

I appreciate any help.
Thank you!

Comment: Could you post more code about `useProduct`? What does it return? Is `product` a ref?

Comment: I edit the post & add more information update the function. Yes product is a reactive object

Comment: @User28 this is right or?

Comment: From `const product = reactive({})` it should be `ref` not `reactive`.

Comment: And you have to keep in mind that `product` is a reactive object (ref) you have to use it via `watcher`, `computed` not just get its value and return.

Comment: oh thank you very much!! I have to use ref instead of reactive & I had one function that was not a computed prop or run within a watcher. This solved it, thanks! @User28

Comment: Glad to hear that. I suggest you try to post an answer of your question to better understand your code.

Comment: yes makes sense! But can you explain to me why I need to use ref instead of reactive? I thought for primitive values I have to use ref and for objects I use reactive?

Comment: Actually, you can use `reactive` if you don't reassign the entire object. If you reassign `product` to `response.data` which is the new object so it no longer references the old reactive object anymore. See more https://stackoverflow.com/a/65262638/2438933.

Answer (score 2):

```
const product = reactive({});
```

product shuld be `ref` and not `reactive`, because I reassign the entire object.

When `product` is reassigned to `response.data` which is the new object so it no longer references the old reactive object anymore.
See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65262638/2438933).

Answer (score 1):

When you're using `reactive` you don't have `.value` but if you use `ref` you the value is inside `.value`. So your composable must be like:

```
export default function useProduct() {
     const product = ref();
    
   async function getProduct(id) {
     try{ 
       const response = await {{http Request}}
       product.value = response.data; // it is a single object
     }catch(err) {
       console.log(err);
     }
   } 
    return {product, getProduct}
}
```

If you use Nuxt 3, you must use `useState` instead of ref [doc](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/composables#usage)