# How can I reset the value of a ref and keep an associated watcher working?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

**UPDATE:**

I have achieved the desired behavior in the MCV by changing `resetArray`:

```js
function resetArray() {
  // myArray.value = [] // old version
  myArray.value.length = 0 // new version
}
```

But I still don't understand why my MCV doesn't work.

**ORIGINAL POST:**

**Background**

In an app I am building, I store data in an a `ref`, created as `const myArray = ref([])`, which takes the form of an array of objects. This array is only changed in the following ways:

1. `myArray.value[index] = {key: value}`
2. `myArray.value = []`.

In particular, at no time is an object in `myArray` modified, it is either created or replaced.

I later added a `watch` which took action on every change to `myArray.value`. I discovered that after resetting `myArray` to `[]`, the watcher stopped getting called.

**Things I have tried:**

1. I confirmed that my usage of `ref` follows the guidelines in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65262638/10067393) regarding `ref` vs `reactive`.
2. Refactoring to use `watchEffect` instead of `watch`. Did not help.
3. Refactoring to use `reactive` rather than `ref`. Did not help.

**My Issue**

In the MCV below, modifying `myArray` by calling `addToArray` works as intended: `myArray.length` is rendered and the first `watch` is triggered.

Calling `resetArray` triggers only the second `watch`, but the first watch **IS NOT** triggered when `addToArray` is called afterwards.

**My Question**

How can I both keep the ability to set `myArray` to `[]` and trigger actions every time `myArray` changes?

**My MCV**

[View my MCV on Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

The below code is the content of `App.vue` in a Vue project created with `npm init vue@latest`:

```html
<script setup>
import {ref, watch} from "vue"

const myArray = ref([])

function addToArray() {
  myArray.value.push("1")
}

function resetArray() {
  myArray.value = []
}

watch(myArray.value, () => {
  console.log("CLICKED!")
})

watch(myArray, () => {
  console.log("RESET! clicked won't get called again!")
})

</script>

<template>
  {{myArray.length}}<br />
  <button @click="addToArray">CLICK ME</button><br />
  <button @click="resetArray">RESET</button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When watching a `ref`, use the `ref` itself -- not its `value` property -- as the watch source (the 1st argument to `watch()`).
2. To observe new array assignments or item additions/removals, pass the `deep:true` option (the 3rd argument to `watch()`):

```js
watch(
  myArray 1️⃣,
  () => { /* handle change */ },
  { deep: true } 2️⃣
)
```

[demo](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)