# Vue ref and reactive, why do we have both?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs3

As per my understanding both `ref` and `reactive` are Composition API methods.

`ref` is used to create reactive object for a single reactive variable like `String` or `Number`. ref values are accessed using the .value property.

`reactive`, on the other hand, is used to create a reactive object that can contain multiple values. `reactive` objects value are accessed directly as objects.

Since both `ref` and `reactive` are ways of creating reactive data, what is the key difference between them other than primitive vs complex object, and why do we have both?

I am learning Vuejs and I tried the below code sample to under ref and reactive.

```
<script> 
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue';

export default { 
setup() { 
const counter = ref(0); 
const counterObj = reactive({counter: 0});

function increment() { 
  counter.value++;
  counterObj.counter++;
}

return { 
  counter, counterObj, increment,
}
}
}
</script>

<template>
<button @click="increment">click me</button>
<span>{{ counter }} {{counterObj.counter}}</span>
</template>
```

Comment: Google is your friend - Internet is full of articles with answers to your question: https://blog.logrocket.com/reactivity-vue-3-composition-api-ref-reactive/, https://dmitripavlutin.com/ref-reactive-differences-vue/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61452458/ref-vs-reactive-in-vue-3 and dozens more, all of them just 2 mouse clicks away.